# Porting libraries for Android

Tags: android, porting

Suppose there are Linux library that has not yet ported to Android. Do you know any article or other information on how to do this?

P.S. Google has not helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't read at http://source.android.com/porting/index.html ?

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.